# Handling multiple jQuery Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to handle the aborted status in using jQuery/Ajax.

I am making multiple ajax calls. If any one of the Ajax call is a success (like one of the `Status` is `200 OK` in the snapshot) then I need to display a success message. If all the Ajax call are with `Aborted` status, then I need to display a failure message.

But it is not working that way; hence a bit confused. Please guide.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon to close out `statusCode`. What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: Instead of checking the status code, why you are not using the success & error callbacks of jQuery ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you can solve your problem even without `async:false`. Use promise to synchronize multiple requests:

```
$(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    var proms = [];
    var errs = 0;
    for (var i = 8078; i < 8085; i++) {
      var port = i;
      proms.push(jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/test/',
          dataType: 'jsonp'
        })
        .then(function(resp) {
          dfd.resolve(resp);
          return resp;
        }, function ( err ) {
          errs++;
          if ( errs === proms.length )
            dfd.reject( err );
        }));
    }

    dfd.promise()
      .then(function ( resp ) {
        // TODO: Add your logic
      }, function () {
        console.log()
        if ( errs === proms.length )
          console.log( 'all fails' );
      });
  })
});
```

Comment: as far as your $.when at the end... i would expect that to always happen in this case, regardless of whether or not one of them pass, but i don't have a suggestion of how to fix that yet